# how to fetch record form database after click on userid in codeigniter?

Tags: html, codeigniter

I am able to retrieve record from data base after click on edit icon(pencil icon) but i am getting particular id details which i written in model.If we will click on edit icon one popup will open and it will display  particular userid  records.for example below image if i will click on userid 3 than record will display, if i will click on userid 4 than record will display,same on userid 5. Please help me in this.

Thanks in advance
 [image] 
[image]

**Controller**

```
public function update_retrive()
{
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$this->load->model("model_add_user");
$d=$this->model_add_user->update_retrive($id);
$data['posts'] = $d;
```

}

**Model**

```
public function update_retrive($id)
{
$this->db->where('userId',$id);/* I have to select multiple userid but how?*/
$this->db->from('add_user');
$q = $this->db->get();
return $q->result();
}
```

**View**

```
<div  class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-bordered" >  
        <thead>
         <tr>  


          <td><b></b></td>
          <td><b></b></td>
            <td><b>userId</b></td>  

            <td><b>firtsname</b></td>  

            <td><b>lastname</b></td>  
            <td><b>mobileno</b></td>  


            <td><b>address</b></td> 
            <td><b>city</b></td>  

            <td><b>email</b></td> 

         </tr> 
          </thead>

         <?php  
         foreach ($user->result() as $row)  
         {  
            ?>

              <tbody><tr >  



        <td><a href="<?php echo site_url('Welcome/delete/'.$row->userId)?>"><img src="http://localhost/CRM/img/delete.png" name="delete_image" ></a></td>
       <!-- <td><a href="<?php echo site_url('Welcome/update/'.$row->userId)?>"><img src="http://localhost/CRM/img/edit.png" name="edit_image" ></a></td>-->
        <td><a id="btnclick" href="<?php echo site_url('Welcome/update_retrive/'.$row->userId)?>"><img src="http://localhost/CRM/img/edit.png" name="edit_image" ></a></td>


            <td><?php echo $row->userId;?></td>  

            <td><?php echo $row->firtsname;?></td>    

            <td><?php echo $row->lastname;?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $row->mobileno;?></td>  


            <td><?php echo $row->address;?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row->city;?></td> 

            <td><?php echo $row->email;?></td> 

            </tr>   </tbody> 
         <?php }  

         ?>  

   </table>  

   <form id="form1">

<div id="popupdiv"  style="display: none">

   <?php foreach($posts as $post){?>

    <input type="text" name="userId" placeholder="USER ID" style="width:200px" value='<?php echo $post->userId;?>'>&nbsp;


    <input type="date" name="date" style="width:200px" value='<?php echo $post->date;?>'>
    <input type="text" name="firtsname" placeholder="FIRST NAME" style="width:200px" value='<?php echo $post->firtsname;?>'>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="middlename" placeholder="MIDDLE NAME" style="width:200px" value='<?php echo $post->middlename;?>'>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="LAST NAME" style="width:200px" value='<?php echo $post->lastname;?>'>&nbsp;

    <input type="text" name="mobileno" placeholder="ENTER MOBILE NO." style="width:200px" value='<?php echo $post->mobileno;?>'>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="landline" placeholder="LANDLINE No." style="width:410px" value='<?php echo $post->landline;?>'>
    <textarea name="address" placeholder="ENTER ADDRESS" style="width:410px" ><?php echo $post->address;?></textarea>

    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="CITY" style="width:200px" value='<?php echo $post->city;?>'>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="locality" placeholder="LOCALITY" style="width:200px" value='<?php echo $post->locality;?>'>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="ENTER EMAIL" style="width:410px" value='<?php echo $post->email;?>'></br>

  <input type="submit" class="submit" name="UPDATE" value="UPDATE" >
<?php }
         ?>
</div>

</form>

  </div>
```

Comment: Are you able to get specific value in popup??

Comment: use ajax to get result correspondent to your clicked id.

Comment: sorry for late reply today stack overflow site was very slow.Mr. Indrasinh Bihola i am able to retrieve data from database if i specify the user name in code.you can check the image above.but i don't want to specify the username

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the ID value in the url 
Try like this

```
<a href = "<?php echo site_url('Welcome/update_retrive');?>/<?php echo 'your id'";?>">edit</a>
```

make a function In your controller

```
    public function update_retrive()
    {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->load->model("model_add_user");
    $d=$this->model_add_user->update_retrive($id);
    $data['posts'] = $d;
}
```

Now in your model

```
public function update_retrive($id)
{

$this->db->where('userId',$id);/* I have to select multiple userid but how?*/
$this->db->from('add_user');
$q = $this->db->get();
return $q->result();
}
```

if you do not want to send the ID in url You can fetch data using ajax as well  http://w3code.in/2015/09/how-to-insert-and-view-data-without-refreshing-page-using-ajax-and-jquery-in-codeigniter

Comment: Mr.Ricky, i this code is not working . i am geeting userid on url  but this is not ans.

Comment: Okay I have updated my answer as you said your are getting ID in the url try to fetch id in your controller with uri segment

Comment: how? Please share the code.it will great help for me

Comment: In above image i clicked on userId 3 and its showing all record in popup.same think i have to click on 4 ,5,etc.all data should be display according to userId.

Comment: Hybreeder when you are selecting the data from the database. You need to store Id dynamically in anchor tag edit <a href = "<?php echo site_url('Welcome/update_retrive');?>/<?php echo 'your id'";?>">edit</a>  I have updated the code above already

Comment: Read this tutorial and to see how to select data from database and store the ID in edit anchor tag dynamically to fetch data from database http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-edit-delete-and-update-data-without-refreshing-page-in-codeigniter/

Comment: Mr.Ricky i think you haven't understand my question

Comment: @Hybreeder you need to send ID on each click to the controller as parameter only then you can fetch the data from the database for that you need to store the ID dynamically in the edit anchor tag.

Comment: Absolutely Right. As above code when i clicked on userId i am getting userid on url thats shit that popup is not displaying.

Comment: are you able to fetch the ID in the controller with this $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

Comment: Yes. I am getting but on url

Comment: Just check the my updated answer and see how to fetch the ID in the controller from url with  $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92560/discussion-between-ricky-and-hybreeder).

Comment: try to echo the $this->uri->segment(3); and see if you are getting the value inside the controller. and let me know

Answer (score 1):

```
Controller:

  $id = $this->input->post('id');

   $data = array("id" => $this->input->post('id'),
                    "****" => $this->input->post('***'),
                    "*****" => $this->input->post('***'),
                    "*****" => $this->input->post('***'),
                    "*****" => $this->input->post('***')
                       );


    $this->load->model('court_page_model');
    $result = $this->court_page_model->update_id($id, $data);


Model:


 public function update_id($id, $data)
{

$this->db->where('***', $id);
$this->db->update('****', $data);
if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return true;

}
```

Comment: Mr.Kumar where should i type the controller code. shall i type in index or create new function?

Comment: your choice should run in both function.

Comment: Mr.I tried your code i created a new function in controller and add your code but i am getting error that "Undefined variable: posts" "Filename: views/index.php" . I have to display reocord in text box.please check my images which i upload above.

Comment: i have to fetch data from data base in popup and display in textbox according to userlid click event so that i can update the record

Comment: in above image i clicked on userId 3 and its showing all record in popup.same think i have to click on 4 ,5,etc.all data should be display according to userId.